# Consumer protection purchasing online course offered by USA company from another country: Which law applies?

Tags: international, online-payment, consumer-protection, online-shopping

I'm from Argentina. A big online learning platform from San Francisco offers course at a price (11 USD) in private navigation, but following the link with common navigation the price change (to 20 USD). The offer does not says exclusive to new clients, so at least in Argentina AFAIK is against the law.

If I'm accesing from here, with intention to pay from here with a Credit Card of a local bank, to consume the service here: Which law applies and how should I reclaim?

I imagine that I don't need to buy a 2000 USD ticket to USA to claim for my rights…

Comment: `I imagine that I don't need to buy a 2000 USD ticket to USA to claim for my rights…` why?

Comment: What is the question here? You pay 11 USD or 20 USD.?

Comment: The question is which law applies and what is the procedure to claim a consumer law violation in this case.

Comment: *The question is which law applies* it seems that specific question may be more suited to law.SE.

Comment: What are you hoping to get when you exercise your "rights"?

Comment: Hi! I hoped both get the course by the original price AND report a complaint. The first was accomplished by creating another account, the second with your link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bait-and-switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bait-and-switch) is annoying and usually illegal.  However, if I'm reading your question correctly, you haven't lost any money, so you don't have any damages.

If all you are trying to do is report them for an advertising violation, you could [report a complaint with California's Attorney General](https://oag.ca.gov/contact/consumer-complaint-against-business-or-company).  Don't expect to get a reward for bringing this to their attention.

Comment: If I'm understanding, the issue isn't bait-and-switch because the company doesn't show one price initially and another later on.  The issue is that the company may show one price if you're in a clean browser with no cookies (i.e. incognito mode) and a different price if some of the information in your cookies leads the company to believe that you're willing to pay more so it shows you a higher price.  In general, that's perfectly OK.

Comment: I wasn't going to purchase with wrong price, but I did lost a lot of time. Creating a new account allow me to purchase with original price. The link will help me to report this problem that may affect another users AND in general e-markey by taking down pruchaser trust in general.